# RewriteRule with optional parameter for redirection in .htacces

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite from:

```
www.domain.de/123/hello
```

to:

```
www.domain.de/index.php?a=$1&b=$2
```

I have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

it works fine. But I also would like that it also works with the input:

```
www.domain.de/123
```

(Here I will get an 404 error.)
The &b shout be empty in this case.
How to achive this?

Comment: What should be target rewrite for `www.domain.de/123/hello` ?

Comment: the target shout be: www.domain.de/index.php?a=$1&b=$2

Comment: a=123 and b=hello or b=empty in case of www.domain.de/123

Comment: I came up with something like this: RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]+)?/$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA,NC] But it only works with given slash what i do not wont.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use these rules with an optional match for 2nd paramter:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Here `(?:/([^/]+))?` is an optional match to make sure above rule matches both:

```
www.domain.de/123/hello
```

and

```
www.domain.de/123
```

Comment: Thx for your support. What does it means an optional match. Do I need two rules? As a single rule it do not work.

Comment: The rule do not work correctly. I do not know why. If I include a file via PHP its seems to be not in root.

Comment: with www.domain.de/123  it works
with www.domain.de/123/hello the includet file semms to be in a different location. I make a include to a php-file witch renders a html. Here are all paths brocken.

Comment: paths broken is different problem not related to my rule. To fix that include add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` .